# Send array as part of x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: arrays, postman

I want to send array using postman. 
the request looks like this:
[image]

Im using postman to execute requests.
I found on the internet to send array via form-data or raw. 
But I need them to be send as x-www-form-urlencoded.
I tried it this way:
[image]

But its wrong because value ads is string not array.

Comment: You can use the above style but just remove `[]` from the value like `1,2,3` from `[1,2,3]` I have done it, It was working fine!!

Comment: This basically works as `1,2,3.split(',')` so it will give `1` `2` `3` but if your sending "abc,@mail.com","de,f@mail.com" then it would give `abc` `@mail.com` `de` `f@mail.com`. If this is not what your looking then you must have to follow write it in below style where we repeat same key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasnt able to solve it via x-www-form-urlencoded even I found solutions like
ads[].id, ads[0].id, ads.id,... It wasnt working.
So I had to write it as raw. and in headers section change it this way.
[image]

And the body is:

```
{ "deleted": "false",
  "ads": 
  [
    {
      "id": 15
    },
    {
      "id": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 35):

I had a bit of a more complex objects.
A class emaillist

```
public class emailist
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String emailaddress { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

A class emailRecipientList

```
public class emailRecipientList
{
    public String procedure { get; set; }
    public String server { get; set; }
    public String filename { get; set; }
    public String fileid { get; set; }
    public List<emailist> emaillists { get; set; }

}
```

And a Task

```
public async Task<System.Xml.XmlElement> postUploadEmailRecipientList([FromBody] emailRecipientList recipientList)
```

Now to send the data as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
[image]

If more elements need to get added just keep increasing the array index.
I tested it on a asp.net WebAPI 2 project and worked fine.

Comment: This should be the best answer as this actually solves the question the the author had originally.

Comment: unfortunately, the emaillists[Index][id] doesn't work for me , when I check postman body request it shows 
"emaillists[Index][id] " = "115"
do you've any Idea why ?

Comment: This is the only answer that works for complex objects. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to pass 1,2,3 in array ads , try with below screenshot

[image]

Comment: it is actually postman screenshot so, no coding things are required.

Comment: Does it work the same way when you want to add a JSON object as one of the keys?

Answer (score 10):

Just figured out how it's done, same as in html forms

cheers

[image]

Comment: Does it work the same way when you want to add a JSON object as one of the keys?

Comment: Kind of, be aware that it is not going to be handled as a json but as a string. If you are using it as a GET parameter, you should url escape or to base64 encode to avoid data corruption.

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Just Use the key without square brackets**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

check this image

[image: as part of x-www-form-urlencoded]

i think you can just repeat the same key and give it different value id for example

Answer (score 0):

For adding array as value, click Bulk Edit in body tab of postman.

It will allow you to input of key value pairs in blank area.

Enter the data of key value pair as below:

```
Id:1

FirstName:John

LastName:Smith
```

For adding bytes of Image in ImageData key array generate the byte array of image and enter or copy/paste as below:

```
Id:1

FirstName:John

LastName:Smith

ImageData:255

ImageData:216

ImageData:255

...

...
```

This will send the data in array for key ImageData.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below screenshot:

[image]

My postman version is 7.13.0.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send data params separately:

```
--data 'some[0]=123'
--data 'some[1]=345'
```

or:

```
--data 'some[0][key1]=123'
--data 'some[0][key2]=345'
```

its will be work