# How to insert data in array field in Mongodb using mongoose and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to insert data in mongodb where one field is of array of an objects type.I am unable  to get how I can add data into array field along with other fields defined in mongoose schema. When I am trying to post data using POSTMAN with below configurations as shown in screenshot:

Its showing games array is empty and showing below error

```
 games: CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "'San and'" (type string) at path "games"
```

[image]

Below is my code:

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotEnv = require('dotenv').config();

const uri = process.env.URI;

const connect = mongoose.connect(uri,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})
                .then(() => console.log("Database connected"))
                .catch((err) => {
                   console.log("Something went wrong",err);
                   process.exit(1);
               });

module.exports = connect;
```

**publisher.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const publisherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  company_name:{
    type: String
  },
  website:{
    type: String
  }
  games: [{
    date: Date,
    name: String
   }]

 });

const publisher = mongoose.model('Publisher',publisherSchema);
module.exports = publisher;
```

Two fields can be inserted as given in below code but How Can I add array field along with these two fields.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connect = require('./db.js');
const publisher = require('./models/publisher.js');
const gaming = require('./models/game.js');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/publish',async (req,res) => {

const { company_name,website,games } = req.body;

const insert = new publisher({company_name,website,games});

try{
    const data = await insert.save();
    res.send(data); 
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is up and runnning at ${port}`));
```

Someone let me know how can I perform this task.

Comment: same as other 2 fields, just pass third array field along with other fields.

Comment: I tried it but it not inserting into array filed. I have attached POSTMAN screenshot in my post take a look.

Comment: You did not pass that field in actual code `new publisher({company_name,website});`, second the postman request array field's value is string, change key name `games[0]` 
 and for more index add new field in request and increment index.

Comment: You are passing the games array wrong from postman, pass it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876323/7177029). Also as @turivishal said destructure the games property in the controller and put it in the Publisher constructor.

Comment: Its showing this error after destructering games value and added it as a filed ` games: CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "'San and'" (type string) at path "games"`

Comment: In my postman I have changed `games` key to `games[ ]`

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @Angus your answer is not working..

Comment: Sorry haven't had a chance to revise. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No its not resolved yet I have added screenshots of an error in my post.Plz let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `CastError` because mongodb is only receiving the string "San and" for the `games` array schema field type.

In Postman, you need to change the `games` *key* to `games[0][name]` to be able to pass "San and" as the game's name. @turivishal and @KunalMukherjee both mention this in the original comments. To add additional array items, you can do so like this in Postman, using `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

key: `games[0][name]` value: `San and` 
key: `games[0][date]` value: `2020-01-01` 
key: `games[1][name]` value: `The Great Game` 
key: `games[1][date]` value: `2020-01-02` 
etc...

**Alternatively**, you can write the JSON directly by selecting the `raw` post body entry method instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Like this:

```json
{
    "company_name": "roveo",
    "website": "www.ro.com",
    "games": [
        {
            "date": "2020-01-01",
            "name": "San and"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-01-02",
            "name": "The Great Game"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the output I get in PostMan using this method:

[image]

And the DB documents in MongoDB:

[image]

Here is the github repo with working code: https://github.com/angusryer/mongo-play

You'll have to point the mongodb uri to your own Cloud Atlas or local server instance. Set up Cloud Atlas by [these steps here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/).

---

Before the question was updated, it looks like like you'd forgotten to extract the games array from your `req.body` in `server.js` as well:

```js
const { company_name, website, games } = req.body; // <-- missed `games`

const insert = new publisher({company_name, website, games}); // <-- and `games` here too

try{
    const data = await insert.save();
    res.send(data); 
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: on doing your solution its showing this error ` games: CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "'San and'" (type string) at path "games"`

Comment: Very late, but for posterity, I've updated the answer.

Comment: its not working array is still empty

Comment: That's odd. On the very first time I sent this POST request, mongo db did not receive the array for some reason. This could have been a caching error on my end--not sure. Either way, every subsequent POST _did_ behave normally, so I've updated my answer to show the result I'm getting. I believe this answers the original question. If it's still not working on your end and you have all of the code above, then there may be another problem.