ASP.NET FormUrlEncode with child List KeyValuePair
I'm calling an API using HTTP POST with a form URL encoded body
The controller I'm calling looks like this:
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomethingAsync(ABCRequest widget)

[DataContract]
public class ABCRequest
{
  [DataMember(Name="name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name="number")]
  public string Number { get; set; }
}

I can happily call the API using the following method
var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "John"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Number", "123")
};

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);

Another API endpoint uses
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething2Async(ABCRequest2 widget)
    
    [DataContract]
    public class ABCRequest2
    {
      [DataMember(Name="name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name="number")]
      public string Number { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name="metadata")]
      public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Metadata { get; set; }
    }

How do I form URL encode the child List?

I'm surprised that your first endpoint works. I'd expect that an unattributed object parameter would use the JSON body rather than form data (hence the [FromForm] attribute). As an aside, you may find less friction by using a JSON payload.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834420/send-array-as-part-of-x-www-form-urlencoded

thanks - I've added in the missing attributes


How do I form URL encode the child List?

According ot your scenario and description along with the share code snippet, I have tried to simulate your scenario and I was able to send send child metadata list with URL encoded value.
In order to form URL encoded child list of KeyValuePair<string, string> in your ABCRequest2 class, you need to flatten the structure into key-value pairs that can be properly encoded.
First of all, you need to convert the child list into individual key-value pairs where each pair has a unique key representing its position or specific identifier.
After constructing the key-value pairs, have to use FormUrlEncodedContent to encode the flat list.
Let's have a look in practice, how we could achieve that:
From a key value pairs encoded content:
var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "John"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("number", "123")
};

var metadataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value2")
};

for (int i = 0; i < metadataList.Count; i++)
{
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"metadata[{i}].Key", metadataList[i].Key));
    formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"metadata[{i}].Value", metadataList[i].Value));
}

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7246/api/Receiving/ReceiveData", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Ok(responseData);
    }
    return BadRequest("Failed to send data");
}

Receiving Controller:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReceivingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ReceiveData")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveData([FromForm] ABCRequest2 widget)
    {
       
        return Ok(widget);
    }
}

Output:




Note: Please refer to this official document for additionl reference and sample
